# How to print in text mode a page displayed with QWebEngineView

Tags: python, pyside6

Using `PySide6` I load an html page in a `QWebEngineView` and print it with:

```
dialog = QPrintDialog(self)
if dialog.exec() == QPrintDialog.Accepted:
    printer = dialog.printer()
    self.wevReport.print(printer)
```

After selecting the printer with the search button it prints the page, but as an image, not as text, which would be the proper thing to do? (`wevReport` is the `QWebEngineView`).

Any suggestions.

**Explanatory note**.
The idea is to get a printout from the `QWebEngineView`, as it can be obtained from a browser.

Comment: Maybe get the text with [QWebEnginePage.toPlainText](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwebenginepage.html#toPlainText) and then render the result with [QTextDocument.print](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtextdocument.html#print).

Comment: Thanks @ekhumoro, But documentation about QWebEnginePage.toPlainText says: "retrieve the page's content converted to plain text, completely stripped of all HTML formatting". So, the structure created with HTML is lost.

Comment: Yes - I know that, which is exactly why I suggested it, since your question asks "how to print in **text** mode". If you actually want to print in *fully formatted*, ***non-text*** *mode*, you're mostly out of luck, because the print support is broken/incomplete in Qt6 (unlike Qt5, where everything seems to work as expected). The best you can do in Qt6 is to [print to pdf](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwebenginepage.html#printToPdf) and then use an external utility to do the printing. (Or otherwise just make do with printing images).